# OIDC RP-initiated logout doesn't work once the first access token got refreshed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to implement the RP-initiated logout as described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/logout.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout).

I have a SPA, a gateway acting as a (BFF) and a spring authorization server (inspired from [ch4mpy's sample demo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)).

The flow is looking like this: the SPA send a get request to the /logout of the gateway who implicitly call the authorization server to get the open-id-token and the logout url, and then from the SPA I get the location header of the response and href to it.

Everything works fine if the access token doesn't change before I logout.

But in my case I configured a short lifespan for my access token and a refresh token grant type to refresh it.
When I refresh an access token, I see that the open-id-token, stored in the AS, is changing (attribute "nonce" disappears and the "exp" and "iat" aren't the same).

**My problem** is that if the access token get refreshed at least once, when I call the logout, I can see that the open-id-token I receive is the first one generated (with "nonce" and the first values of "exp" and "iat"), and not the updated one.

Then of course my logout in the AS throws an exception in OidcLogoutAuthentificationProvider.authenticate since no open-id-token in DB matches.

Some context: I'm using spring-boot 3.1.4.

The AS:

```
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

http.cors(withDefaults())
    .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
    .oidc(withDefaults());
```

---

```
RegisteredClient client = RegisteredClient.withId("1")
                                          .clientId(clientId)
                                          .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                                          .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                                          .redirectUri(gatewayUri + "/login/oauth2/code/myoauth2")
                                          .postLogoutRedirectUri(gatewayUri + "/ui/login")
                                          .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                                          .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                                          .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                                          .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                                          .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                                                                      .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                                                                      .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(4))
                                                                      .build())
                                          .build();
```

BFF:

```
http.oauth2Login(login -> {
        login.authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/ui/login?success=true"));
        login.authenticationFailureHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationFailureHandler("/ui/login?success=fail"));
    })
    .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository, postLogoutRedirectUri)));
```

---

```
static class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements ServerLogoutSuccessHandler {

    private final OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler delegate;

    public CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, String postLogoutRedirectUri) {
        this.delegate = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        this.delegate.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(postLogoutRedirectUri);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> onLogoutSuccess(WebFilterExchange exchange, Authentication authentication) {
        return delegate.onLogoutSuccess(exchange, authentication)
                       .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                           exchange.getExchange()
                                   .getResponse()
                                   .setStatusCode(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                       }));
    }
}
```

---

```
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                provider:
                    spring:
                        issuer-uri: ${backend-uri}
                registration:
                    spring:
                        provider: spring
                        client-id: ${client-id}
                        client-secret: ${client-secret}
                        authorization-grant-type:
                            - authorization_code
                            - refresh_token
                        redirect-uri: ${gateway-uri}/login/oauth2/code/myoauth2
                        scope:
                            - openid
                            - profile
            resourceserver:
                jwt:
                    issuer-uri: ${backend-uri}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ID tokens and access tokens are not the same thing.

What the RP-Initiated Logout request contains is an ID token, not an access token.

For `refresh_token` flow, the `offline_access` scope must be requested in the the initial `authorization_code` flow. For the ID token to be refreshed with other tokens, both `openid` and `offline_access` scopes must be requested with the `refresh_token` request.

In your client registration, it seems that you are not requesting the `offline_access` scope, which is probably why the tokens refreshing does not happen has you expect.

Comment: First of all, thank your for all your help.
I'm aware of the difference between acess and the open-id token, what I'm saying is when I refresh the access token, the oidc-token also changes.
I tried to add the offline_access scope as you suggested, but it didn't change anything. When I read the documentation about it, it doesn't seems to match what I want to do or facing.
This scope seems only mandatory when using Keycloack AS which is not my case.

Comment: `offline_access` has nothing specific to Keycloak, it is part of [OpenID standard](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#Scopes). It allows the client to get new tokens on behalf of the user (refresh the tokens the client already has), even if the user does not have an active session on the authorization server (note that I wrote authorization server and not client there).